# Count the number of unique values for each column of a submatrix in a fast manner

Tags: matlab, performance, matrix, permutation, accumarray

I have a matrix `X` with tens of rows and thousands of columns, all elements are categorical and re-organized to an index matrix. For example, `ith` column `X(:,i) = [-1,-1,0,2,1,2]'` is converted to `X2(:,i) = ic` of `[x,ia,ic] = unique(X(:,i))`, for convenient use of function `accumarray`. I randomly selected a submatrix from the matrix and counted the number of unique values of each column of the submatrix. I performed this procedure 10,000 times. I know several methods for counting number of unique values in a column, the fasted way I found so far is shown below:

```
mx = max(X);
for iter = 1:numperm
    for j = 1:ny
        ky = yrand(:,iter)==uy(j);
        % select submatrix from X where all rows correspond to rows in y that y equals to uy(j)
        Xk = X(ky,:);
        % specify the sites where to put the number of each unique value
        mxj = mx*(j-1);
        mxi = mxj+1;
        mxk = max(Xk)+mxj;
        % iteration to count number of unique values in each column of the submatrix
        for i = 1:c
            pxs(mxi(i):mxk(i),i) = accumarray(Xk(:,i),1);
        end
    end
end
```

This is a way to perform random permutation test to calculate information gain between a data matrix `X` of size `n by c` and categorical variable `y`, under which `y` is randomly permutated. In above codes, all randomly permutated `y` are stored in matrix `yrand`, and the number of permutations is `numperm`. The unique values of `y` are stored in `uy` and the unique number is `ny`. In each iteration of `1:numperm`, submatrix `Xk` is selected according to the unique element of `y` and number of unique elements in each column of this submatrix is counted and stored in matrix `pxs`.

The most time costly section in the above code is the iterations of `i = 1:c` for large `c`.

Is it possible to perform the function `accumarray` in a matrix manner to avoid `for` loop? How else can I improve the above code?

**-------**

As requested, a simplified test function including above codes is provided as

```
%% test
function test(x,y)

[r,c] = size(x);
x2 = x;
numperm = 1000;

% convert the original matrix to index matrix for suitable and fast use of accumarray function
for i = 1:c
    [~,~,ic] = unique(x(:,i));
    x2(:,i) = ic;
end

% get 'numperm' rand permutations of y
yrand(r, numperm) = 0;
for i = 1:numperm
    yrand(:,i) = y(randperm(r));
end

% get statistic of y
uy = unique(y);
nuy = numel(uy);

% main iterations
mx = max(x2);
pxs(max(mx),c) = 0;
for iter = 1:numperm
    for j = 1:nuy
        ky = yrand(:,iter)==uy(j);
        xk = x2(ky,:);
        mxj = mx*(j-1);
        mxk = max(xk)+mxj;
        mxi = mxj+1;
        for i = 1:c
            pxs(mxi(i):mxk(i),i) = accumarray(xk(:,i),1);
        end
    end
end
```

And a test data

```
x = round(randn(60,3000));
y = [ones(30,1);ones(30,1)*-1];
```

Test the function

```
tic; test(x,y); toc
```

return `Elapsed time is 15.391628 seconds.` in my computer. In the test function, 1000 permutations is set. So if I perform 10,000 permutation and do some additional computations (are negligible comparing to the above code), time more than `150 s` is expected. I think whether the code can be improved. Intuitively, perform `accumarray` in a matrix manner can save lots of time. Can I?

Comment: Your description is a bit hard to follow.. Could you please add some code to the question that generates an input similar to what you have (e.g. using `rng(42528955)` and `randi`), and **show** the expected output ([mcve])? Questions dealing with the improvement of existing code should have, in my opinion, some functioning baseline code.

Comment: @Dev-iL Thanks. A simple function with a testing data is added.

Comment: You can use `hist` or `histcount`. Assume I have a 5 * 5 array and I want to find histcount of each column. `a=randi(10,5,5);h=hist(a,1:10)`

Comment: @rahnema1 This is excellent! It runs five times faster than mine if the loop `for i = 1:c` is replaced by the single line `pxs(mmx*(j-1)+1:mmx*j,:)=hist(x2(ky,:), xbin)`, where `xbin=(0.5:1:max(mx)-0.5)'`. Thanks.

Comment: But I still wonder whether there exists a built-in function to do same thing. This would be even better.

Comment: @rahnema1 would you please post your solution as an answer? Elkan - you can do it too - just answer your own question (you don't have to accept the answer).

Comment: @Dev-iL to answer the question I should read whole of the question. I answered title of the question in the comments but it  seems that more extra things is considered in the question.

Comment: @Dev-iL Only a few revision is made to my code which have been mentioned in my comment, i.e., just change the `for i=1:c;...; end` loop to a single line `pxs(mmx*(j-1)+1:mmx*j,:)=hist(x2(ky,:), xbin)`. New update is use function `histc`. I don't know whether this is enough to be shown as an answer.

Comment: @Elkan Why not? You can always improve it later...

Comment: @Dev-iL Has been added as new answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The way suggested by @rahnema1 has significantly improved the calculations, so I posted my answer here, as also requested by @Dev-iL.

```
%% test
function test(x,y)

[r,c] = size(x);
x2 = x;
numperm = 1000;

% convert the original matrix to index matrix for suitable and fast use of accumarray function
for i = 1:c
    [~,~,ic] = unique(x(:,i));
    x2(:,i) = ic;
end

% get 'numperm' rand permutations of y
yrand(r, numperm) = 0;
for i = 1:numperm
    yrand(:,i) = y(randperm(r));
end

% get statistic of y
uy = unique(y);
nuy = numel(uy);

% main iterations
mx = max(max(x2));
% preallocation
pxs(mx*nuy,c) = 0;
% set the edges of the bin for function histc
binrg = (1:mx)';
% preallocation of the range of matrix into which the results will be stored
mxr = mx*(0:nuy);
for iter = 1:numperm
    yt = yrand(:,iter);
    for j = 1:nuy
        pxs(mxr(j)+1:mxr(j),:) = histc(x2(yt==uy(j)),binrg);
    end
end
```

Test results:

```
>> x = round(randn(60,3000));
>> y = [ones(30,1);ones(30,1)*-1];
>> tic; test(x,y); toc
Elapsed time is 15.632962 seconds.
>> tic; test(x,y); toc % using the way suggested by rahnema1, i.e., revised function posted above
Elapsed time is 2.900463 seconds.
```